# Extending the GUI fields

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I would like to extend the individual GUI elements, do some custom processing and later call the default function.

For example: Whenever a particular Input Element is selected in the Component window, I would like show a TooTip to the user associated with that field.

Kindly provide some pointers.

> #### #
>
> Sorry for my earlier attempt in framing the question Reframing it
>   again.
>
> #### #
>
> Actually I have a schema with four fields, My requirement is to show a
>   help text, whenever the focus is on a particular field.
>
> One of the field holds Country Name: So when the focus is on the
>   Country Name ( Single Text Field ) I need to show "Please enter the
>   Country Name" on the text field. So that the editor understands the
>   same, without using the Schema Description field.
>
> So my question was can we capture the events for all types of fields (
>   like Multimedia, RTF, Single Line ) in the Component Edit view ?
>
> Hope was able to make my question more clear

Answer (score 6):

You would have to extend the Component-edit screen for this. I suggest you read-up on Tridion GUI extensions:

- [www.sdltridionworld.com](http://www.sdltridionworld.com),
- [SDLLivecontent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?action=html&resource=login.html)
- [Tridion Developer blog](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/)

Also, searching stackoverlow might help: [Extending the publish screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240878/extending-the-current-publishing-unpublishing-screen)

A valuable source of examples is the PowerTools project. You can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/)

Asking a more specific question allows us to help you more specific.

Comment: Was away on a training so could'nt respond back. Yes, I think I will have to extend the Component Edit Screen, but the challenge is wrt to the config file. Can you please some examples where the Componnet eist screen has been extended.